# Objective-C contentsOfDirectoryAtURL need filenames instead complete path

Tags: objective-c, filenames, nsfilemanager, file-type

I´m using this piece of code to get the files contained in folder pathTo_Folder.
What I get is something like this:
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Tech-2.jpg",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Tech-3.jpg",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Tech-4.jpg",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Terra-1.jpg",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Terra-2.jpg",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Terra-3.jpg",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Terra-4.png",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Terra-5.png",
    "file://localhost/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen/Terra-6.jpg"

I wonder if there is a way to get only the filename without the containing folder like "Tech-2.jpg"

```
NSString *pathTo_Folder = @"/Users/ronny/DEV/0200-ObjC4/ModernTimes/DrawingFun/linen";

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *theFiles =  [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:
                      [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathTo_Folder]
                                includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLNameKey]
                                                   options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                     error:nil];
```

Greetings from Switzerland, Ronald Hofmann

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for( NSURL* fileURL in theFiles ) {
  NSString* filename = [fileURL lastPathComponent];
  // do things with the filename
}
```

As per the comments, if you just want the filenames:

```
// Note, this is not very efficient, and it's especially inefficient if
// you then go ahead and iterate the resultant array
NSArray* filenames = [theFiles valueForKeyPath:@"lastPathComponent"];
```

Comment: That´s what I already thought of. But can´t I do it without looping through the array?

Comment: @RonaldHofmann Usually when you get a list of files, you want to process them in some way... but if you just want the filenames in one line, you can get that. I'll update my answer (however, if you do iterate through *that* list later, it's definitely far more efficient to just iterate the original list and process them there).

Comment: What do you mean by 'this is not very efficient'? For me everything is more efficient than looping thru an array. Is it slow? I tried what you supposed and it does the job well.

Comment: @RonaldHofmann Yes, it will also loop through the array, just internally. There's really no getting around that bit. Also, since it uses the KVC system instead of directly calling the method, it's not as efficient. All that said, however, as long as you're not seeing a performance problem, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

NSURL has a method `lastPathComponent` that does exactly what you need.